# dark grey layer appears on the top of my webview with navigation controller

Tags: uiwebview, navigationbar, navigationcontroller

I've a UIWebView. Everything is fine if I don't add navigation controller. But If I add, a dark grey layer on the top of my uiwebview appears. I don't understand what is wrong, I'm just adding a uiwebview and haven't written a line of code about sizing or layout.

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRTuU.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYnti.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your navigation bar's translucent property is set to YES. Set it to NO and the dark grey background will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide that navigation bar by adding this:

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

to the view controller's ViewDidLoad()